# Modify the rows of a tensor at specific indices given by a list (Pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `X` with shape (N,M) and a list of indices `idx_list`.
I would like to modify `X` but only at the rows given by `idx_list`.
So I'd like to do something like this:

```
X[idx_list, :] = Y
```

`Y` is a tensor with shape `(len(idx_list), M)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is mentioned in your question. The usual slicing notation that's used in numpy arrays works well with PyTorch tensors as well.

```py
X[idx_list, :] = Y
```

Here's a screenshot from Jupyter notebook illustrating it:
[image]

Your approach posted as answer would work too

```py
X[(torch.tensor(idx_list),)] = Y
```

However, you do not need to complicate it like this by converting the `idx_list` into a tensor. Slicing is preferably done using standard Python lists.

Comment: Very clear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well:

```
X[(torch.tensor(idx_list),)] = Y
```